# What is causing "int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not '_NoValueType'" with column subset retrieval?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am using Python 3.9, pandas 2.1.3, numpy 1.26.2, on MacOS. My code is as below:

```py
data_subset_1 = pd.read_csv("my_path_1")
data_subset_2 = pd.read_csv("my_path_2")

data_subset_1["subset"] = "subset_1"
data_subset_2["subset"] = "subset_2"

agg = pd.concat((data_subset_1, data_subset_2))
agg = agg[["col1", "col2", "col3"]]
```

And input data looks like below

my_path_1

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
0.5,0.3,5,7
```

my_path_2

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
0.3,0.1,3,9
```

This fails at the last line with a stack trace:

```
agg = agg[["col1", "col2", "col3"]]
  File "/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3908, in __getitem__
    data = self._take_with_is_copy(indexer, axis=1)
  File "/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4088, in _take_with_is_copy
    result = self.take(indices=indices, axis=axis)
  File "/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4068, in take
    new_data = self._mgr.take(
  File "/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 877, in take
    return self.reindex_indexer(
  File "/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 663, in reindex_indexer
    new_blocks = self._slice_take_blocks_ax0(
  File "/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 809, in _slice_take_blocks_ax0
    max_len = max(len(mgr_locs), taker.max() + 1)
  File "/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 41, in _amax
    return umr_maximum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims, initial, where)
```

This is raised from the `umr_maximum` C code under the hood from what I can figure. I can verify it is passing a list of int i.e. column indices from the indexer. Something really strange must be happening that I have no idea how to troubleshoot next

Comment: Did you look at `agg` after concat?  What are the column names?

Comment: Column names were correct. I am having functions like `df.describe` failing also, it is something odd with `numpy.max`

Comment: If you can't describe `agg`, how about the two component frames?

Comment: You'll need to make a [mre] for us to help. For specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). FWIW, it smells like a bug, but to report it, you'll also want an MRE.

Comment: This is the entirety of the code to reproduce, except for the imports. Unless I can share my entire env this is as close I can get to an MRE

Comment: @Layman An MRE isn't just code, it's also inputs, i.e. data from `my_path_1` and `my_path_2`. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341) for details.

Comment: @hpaulj also failing

Comment: @wjandrea it is reproing with any mock input I can come up with on my end

Comment: There's something wrong with those dataframes as loaded.  Since they come from csv files, it may be possible to post excerpts of those files, just enough recreate the datasets and problems.

Comment: It reproes with the examples I included

Comment: With the input and code that you provided the example runs for me and outputs the expected result. I am guessing that either your csv's are faulty/different from what you provided, or something in your installation is not correct, have you tried running it in a fresh virtual environment?

Comment: I can't repro with Pandas 2.1.3 and Python 3.9. See if you can repro in a fresh env. Your version of NumPy might be relevant; I'm using 1.26.2.

Comment: Same np version, also adding to the post